# C++ - Optimizing my GC

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

Here is my Garbage collector code: (Where it finds that object unreachable anymore)

```
HEADER* ptr;
static int gc_checked_count;
static void** gc_checked_array;//=malloc(10000);

//This method called when the the pointer in this class is changing.
inline void Destruct() {
    //If the pointer is null or it is alright pointed from the stack then
    if ((!ptr?true:ptr->getOnStack()))
        //exit.
        return;
    //GC_THROW_USED uses this variable. - need to zero it.
    gc_checked_count=0;
    try {
        GC_THROW_USED(ptr);
        //If this function didn't threw a bool ,then run it's finalize method
        //getType is temporary as function pointer.
        ((void(*)(void*))ptr->getType())(ptr);
        //, free his information
        free(ptr->getArray());
        //, free itself
        free(ptr);
        //and zero `ptr` because it isn't valid anymore.
        ptr=0;
    }
    catch (bool x) {
        //If reachable then don't do anything to this object.
        //Keep yourself alive because life is good :).
    }
}

inline void GC_THROW_USED(HEADER* p) {
    //Check if this pointer didn't checked by this method
    for (uint i=0;i<gc_checked_count;++i)
        //, if yes then
        if (gc_checked_array[i]==p)
            //exit.
            return;
    //Append this pointer to the checked list
    gc_checked_array[gc_checked_count++]=p;
    //If this pointer is pointed on the stack then
    if (p->getOnStack())
        //throw. (it says that `ptr` is reachable.)
        throw false;
    uint count=p->getCount();
    HEADER** pArray=(HEADER**)p->getArray();
    for (uint i=0;i<count;++i)
        //Run this method on it's containers too. (Until exception or there is no object to run on)
        GC_THROW_USED(pArray[i]);
}
```

Before any statement, there is a comment that explain it.
Like you saw, this GC runs on pointer's containers (Who 'know' this pointer) until
it found that a container is on the stack and then it's mean that this object
is reachable. If not then finalize this object and free it.

**THE REAL QUESTION:** There is a way to optimize this process to improve performance?
The `//Run this method on it's containers too. (Until exception or there is no object to run on)` part (in the last few lines in the code) I can cut it and it'll run without bugs?

I am a little confused because this GC method just popped up in my brain and it works without bugs.

Comment: Let me just note: Don't use exceptions for the normal case.

Comment: @MarkB Exceptions are slow? EDIT: Oops this question is about optimizing anyway :S. Thanks!

Comment: @DividedByZero: performance is not really relevant: it's not an exception if it's a normal case.

Comment: @Fanael The exception is just to drop all the functions that called on the callstack. I don't want the function to return something. It is slow to return a value each call.

Comment: @DividedByZero The fact that you *can* use exceptions to do that doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: @DividedByZero: Did you even profile the difference? Throwing an exception is much slower than returning a value, especially considering inlining. You're just guessing at this point. Get some data.

Comment: @GManNickG Ok second I'll profile this.

Comment: How not a real question? I marked my question. -_-

Answer (score 2):

If your application needs garbage collection, I would actually suggest using one of the many languages that already natively support it rather than attempting to add such a feature to C++.

If however your need is a sane memory management model within C++, you should make use of RAII via smart pointers. For memory management this means using an appropriate smart pointer to handle all your memory allocation needs. You can get these pointers either through C++11 or if that's not available to you, through boost.

Comment: I am creating language that interpret in the end to C++. I want to put GC in it. I don't want to interpret it to another proglang or use smart pointer. I want something without bugs (There is no ultimate smart pointer) or change to managed proglang (My interpret purposes are performance and easy)

Comment: @DividedByZero: You seem to be implying that because there is no ultimate smart pointer, those that exist have bugs? Do you think you've just created some ultimate garbage collector?

Comment: @GManNickG It doesn't fell yet. BTW the `ultimate smart pointer` I meant there are situations that you need to choose which smart pointer to use. Here you don't need to think.